# Error while runnung command "flutter run"

Tags: android-studio, flutter

How to resolve this error ->

When i run the `flutter run` command it gives following error.

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
```

Even `flutter doctor -v` doesn't show any error.

Screenshot of that error:
[image: Screenshot of that error]

Comment: The `Ankit` directory does contain a `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but I think you are trying to run a project that doesn't exits, or is there a project with the root directly in your users folder?

So maybe you should try to navigate to your project or create one if you haven't already.

You can create a new project from command prompt by entering.

```
flutter create myapp
```

After you have created the new project you can run it by:

```
cd myapp
flutter run
```

More information about that can be found here: [Get Started: Test Drive](https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#terminal)